# What is the best way to assign an ID to a deposit?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am writing a code for an escrow. What would be the best way to get an id for the releaseDeposit(id) function? I know there are a few options, such as using counters or mapping, however, is there one that would be the preferred way, and how would it be implemented?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Escrow {
    address owner;

    struct Deposit {
        uint256 depositAmount;
        address buyer;
        address seller;}

    constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;}

    Deposit[] public activeDeposits;

    function deposit(address seller) public payable {

        Deposit memory newDeposit = Deposit(

        msg.value,
        msg.sender,
        seller);

    activeDeposits.push(newDeposit);

    function releaseDeposit(uint256 id) public {

        require (msg.sender == activeDeposits[id].buyer,
        "Only maker of the deposit can release deposit.");

        payable(activeDeposits[id].seller).transfer(activeDeposits[id].depositAmount);}
}
```

Comment: You might consider using the seller's or buyer's address or a hash of both together. (if they want more than one deposit, they can make more than one address)

Comment: Using only the seller's or buyer's address is not enough, as the same address can make a few deposits of different sizes. Could you provide an example of hashing them together and using the hash as an ID?